# AXIOS Status 400 Bad Request on React Front End

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am building an authentication component on React.
When the wrong password/username is entered, I am expecting a Status 400 with the message: 'Invalid email or password' on the front end

Instead, I am getting Status 400 with the message: 'Request failed with status code 400'. I used postman to simulate a bad login and I do get the message : 'Invalid email or password'

When I tried a successful login on my frontend, everything works and I get a JWT token.

I also did a console.log on the backend and I can see that the data did reach the backend. The problem seems to be that the error is not handled by the front end properly.

Can someone take a look and let me know what is the problem? thank you.

Backend Post routes

```
router.post('/signin', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    if (!user) return res.status(400).send('Invalid email or password')
    //compare the password with the password in database 
    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
    if (!validPassword) return res.status(400).send('Invalid email or password')
    const token = user.generateAuthToken()
    // res.send(token)
    res.header('x-auth-token', token).send(_.pick(user, ['_id', 'name)', 'email']))
})
```

Frontend React

```
 doSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const { data } = this.state

        try {
            console.log(data)
            await userService.signIn(data)
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex.message)
            if (ex && ex.response.status === 400) {
                let errors = { ...this.state.errors }
                errors.email = ex.message
                this.setState({errors})
            }

        }
    }
```

userService

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { SIGN_UP, SIGN_IN } from '../Components/constant/constant';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


export default {

    register: (user) => {

        console.log(user, 'axios')
        axios.post(SIGN_UP, {
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password,
            name: user.name
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response, 'response')
            console.log(response)
            if (response.status === 200) {
                window.location = '/signupsuccessful'
            }
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    },

    signIn: async (data) => {
        console.log('sign in user service')
        await axios.post(SIGN_IN, {
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password,
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just missed the `response` part of the exception in the `doSubmit` function of the React code, so you get the exception message and not the response message from the request.

### Change

```
errors.email = ex.message
```

### To

```
errors.email = ex.response.data
```

### Example

```
if (ex && ex.response.status === 400) {
  let errors = { ...this.state.errors }
  errors.email = ex.response.data
  this.setState({errors})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong in your code just to get the response from the error case in axios you have to get like so:

```
...
.catch((error)=>console.log(error.response.data))
```

**EDIT**: for more details
So what you have to do in your code is:

**Backend**

don't send a string i recommend
send a json

```
res.status(400).send({message:'Invalid email or password'})
```

**FrontEnd**

```
if (ex && ex.response.status === 400) {
    let errors = { ...this.state.errors }
    errors.email = ex.response.data.message
    this.setState({errors})
}
```

Comment: If I use your approach, the error will be handled at userServices but i want it to be handled at Front end react because i want to display the error messages.

Comment: I know i just wanted to put you on the right path by mentioning the response attribute i will update the answer for more details